# How do I pass a python, SK Learn MinMaxScaler from one component to another on the Google Cloud Platfrom's Vertex AI pipelines?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I am developing a machine learning pipeline with `kubeflow` on the `GCP` `Vertex AI` platform.  At one step, I scale my training data using the `MinMaxScaler` from the `scikit learn` package.  I need to out that scaler in order to import it into a custom component further down the pipeline.  Does that scaler object need to be output as an `artifact` or a `model`?  Or something else?

When I output a data set from a component I use the command `df.to_pickle(output_dataset_name)` based on the output name parameter in the function of the custom component.  How would I do that for a sk-learn object?